# C find static array size

Tags: c, arrays, static

```
static char* theFruit[] = {
    "lemon",
    "orange",
    "apple",
    "banana"
};
```

I know the size is 4 by looking at this array. How do I programmatically find the size of this array in C? I do not want the size in bytes.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
sizeof(theFruit) / sizeof(theFruit[0])
```

Note that `sizeof(theFruit[0]) == sizeof(char *)`, a constant.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the way to it. That's why he's getting +1s.... :-). But only with arrays, as you have in your question. Not with pointers.

Comment: @eat_a_lemon: depends on what you call every case :) It works for static and automatic arrays, not `malloc`'d ones. Note that the size of the array is always a multiple of the size of the first element, so the division is guaranteed to work, and that `sizeof` only looks at types, so it even works for arrays with zero elements.

Comment: I think what I am confused about is that the entries are variable size because they are strings.

Comment: @eat_a_lemon: the entries aren't strings; they're `char*`s *pointing to* strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good thing to have this macro around.

```
#define SIZEOF(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use const char* instead as they will be stored in read-only place. And to get size of array
`unsigned size = sizeof(theFruit)/sizeof(*theFruit);`
Both *theFruit and theFruit[0] are same.